# What in the implementation needs to change in order for a left associative operator to become right associative?

Tags: haskell, associative, associativity

I'm reading up on Haskell and as expected there are some operators that are left associative and others that are right associative. That got me thinking, how would the implementation differ for a new operator ¤, when comparing the left associative version versus the right associative version?

So given `[1,2] ¤ [3,4] ¤ [5,6]`, what changes in the implementation if I want this to be interpreted as `(([1,2] ¤ [3,4]) ¤ [5,6])` versus `([1,2] ¤ ([3,4] ¤ [5,6]))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To state that an operator is left- or right-associative, one can use a [fixity declaration](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html).

For instance

```
infixl 5 .+.                  -- left associative
infixr 5 .-.                  -- right associative
infix  5 .=.                  -- not associative
```

The last one causes `x .=. y .=. z` to be a parse error, requiring explicit parentheses.

The number `5` above is the precedence level, and should be chosen following the level of other operators (e.g. `(+)` is level 6, while `($)` has level 0).

Comment: Also noteworthy - the default fixity is `infixl 9`, where 9 is the highest precedence offered to infix operators at 0 is the lowest. Also, you can specify the fixity of a normal function used infix by putting the name in backticks, the same as you do when actually using it infix.

Comment: As i understand it then, your `.+.`, `.-.`, and `.=.` represent the operators in your examples there. Are the dots part of the operator or the fixity syntax?

Comment: @PatrikIselind They are part of the name of the operator. `infixl 5 %*+` would also be OK, for operator `%*+`.